# Angular 12 CLI is a working solution for supporting pug templates?

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, pug

Is there an adequate solution to support .pug templates for angular cli 12?

ng-cli-pug-loader it does not work and gives an error

```
Error: src/app/app.component.pug:26:2 - error NG5002: Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.)
```

Comment: Same question. I use `{"test":/\.pug$/,"use":["raw-loader",{"loader":"pug-html-loader","options":{"doctype":"html"}}]}` but do not work in Angular 13.